# iOS MKMapView and MKPolyLine

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm new to iOS programming and am not sure what is wrong with this code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *locations = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * points.count/2);
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < points.count; i++)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D point = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[points objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue], [[points objectAtIndex:++i] doubleValue]);

    // Fill the array.
    locations[count] = point;
    count++;

    NSLog(@"%@", locations[count-1].latitude);
    NSLog(@"%@", locations[count-1].longitude);
}


// Create the polyline based on the array of points.

MKPolyline *routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locations count:points.count/2];


MKPolylineView *routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:routeLine];
routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

// Add overlay to map.
[mapOutlet addOverlay:routeLine];
[mapOutlet setVisibleMapRect:routeLine.boundingMapRect];

// clear the memory allocated earlier for the points.
free(locations);
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the first call to NSLOG(). Any thoughts?

FYI: 'points' is an array of strings containing latitude and longitude values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `%@` to print a value, NSLog tries to use the argument as an object pointer but these are double float values.  Use the `%f` to print doubles:

```
NSLog(@"%f", locations[count-1].latitude);
NSLog(@"%f", locations[count-1].longitude);
```